# Git credential issue when working with Jenkins End-to-End Multibranch Pipeline Project Creation

Tags: linux, git, docker, jenkins

[Image of Error - Git credential validation failed with an unexpected error. Please try again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACHml.png)

When working on the initial End-to-End Multibranch Pipeline Project Creation project for Jenkins, it is asking for credentials when connecting to the local /home/user_name/GitHub/building-a-multibranch-pipeline-project to access the local git files. I have tried an array of different approaches form providing my system credentials to my git credentials but nothing seems to work.

The workflow for this project is as follows:

- install Jenkins
- run docker instance code below
- fork and clone git repo locally into /home/user_name/GitHub
- create a pipeline with Git <- this is where the Git error occurs
- Tutorial link: https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/

I realize this is probably a very simple problem, but I greatly appreciate any help.

```
  --rm \
  -u root \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v "$HOME":/home \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if using the file protocol as an URL would be enough to convince Jenkins and its Credential plugin that is does *not* need username/password:

```
file:///home/GitHub/building-a-multibranch-project
```

The idea is: for local file-based access, there is no authentication with Git.